# ZOS error in running JBERET java batch program

Tags: mainframe, zos, jsr352, java-batch, jberet

I am trying to run [this](https://github.com/kaape/jberet-standalone-example) jberet java batch program in z/OS but, getting the following exception. This seems to be something wrt permissions in z/OS because, the same executable (fat/uber) jar ran fine in the windows machines.

```
 Oct 05, 2017 9:07:41 AM org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup <clinit>
 INFO: WELD-000900: 2.4.5 (Final) Oct 05, 2017 9:07:41 AM org.jboss.weld.environment.deployment.discovery.ReflectionDiscoveryStrategy processAnnotatedDiscovery
 INFO: WELD-ENV-000014: Falling back to Java Reflection for bean-discovery-mode="annotated" discovery. Add org.jboss:jandex to the classpath to speed-up startup.
 Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.batch.operations.JobOperator: Provider org.jberet.operations.JobOperatorImpl could not be instantiated
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:236)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:193)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:389)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:457)
    at javax.batch.runtime.BatchRuntime$1.run(BatchRuntime.java:51)
    at javax.batch.runtime.BatchRuntime$1.run(BatchRuntime.java:46)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:396)
    at javax.batch.runtime.BatchRuntime.getJobOperator(BatchRuntime.java:46)
    at com.citi.Report.App.main(App.java:18)
 Caused by: com.ibm.crypto.hdwrCCA.provider.JCECCARuntimeException: Hardware error from call CSNBRNGL returnCode 8 reasonCode 16000
    at com.ibm.crypto.hdwrCCA.provider.SecureRandom.engineNextBytes(SecureRandom.java:40)
    at java.security.SecureRandom.nextBytes(SecureRandom.java:470)
    at java.util.UUID.randomUUID(UUID.java:157)
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.se.Weld.initialize(Weld.java:779)
    at org.jberet.se.SEArtifactFactory.<init>(SEArtifactFactory.java:29)
    at org.jberet.se.BatchSEEnvironment.getArtifactFactory(BatchSEEnvironment.java:133)
    at org.jberet.operations.JobOperatorImpl.<init>(JobOperatorImpl.java:93)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1887)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:385)
    ... 6 more
```

**What could be the solution for this error ?**

```
Hardware error from call CSNBRNGL returnCode 8 reasonCode 16000
```

Update:
     This batch program does not read/write to any mainframe files , it is just a hello world example.  Few significant  things this batch program does 
         1. WELD reading the beans.xml 
          2. JBeret reading the JBERET.properties
          3. Create a H2 DB for using as job repository

Am wondering if any of these could be needing those additional permissions.

Answer (score 3):

The IBM JCE-implementation tries to call the cryptgraphic service `CSNBRNGL` which fails.

Reason code 16000 says

> RACF failed your request to use this service.

Looking further one can find that the user executing the code needs access (READ should be sufficient) to the resource `CSFRNGL` in the class `CSFSERV`.

Since there will probably some more services that are required it probably is not the only resource that you need to access, so perhaps a generic profile along the lines of `CSF*` could be considered.

See [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.csfb300/ctlserv.htm) for a list of all `CSFSERV` RACF-resources and the services they protect.

Comment: Thanks, will ask our Zos folks to have a look at this link.